# usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd

Tags: 16.04, jack, passwd, user-mode-linux

I get this massage: 
`usermod: Permission denied.
usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later`
after trying to add myself to audio group by:
`usermod -a -G audio USERNAME`.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Did you try prefacing the command with `sudo`?

Comment: sudo usermod -a -G audio USERNAME will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run `usermod` as root, you can do this with `sudo`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio USERNAME
```

Comment: For me `sudo usermod -a -G audio USERNAME`
didnt work, it gave me this result: > usermod: Permission denied. > usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later. However sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0 did the trick