# Failed to install opendkim in webmin (Ubuntu): "useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later."

Tags: apt, server, webmin, useradd

I tried to install opendkim on the Ubuntu server using the Webmin command line, with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -y install opendkim opendkim-tools
```

But I encounter a number of errors:

```
Setting up opendkim (2.11.0~alpha-11build1) ...
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
adduser: `/usr/sbin/useradd -d /var/run/opendkim -g opendkim -s /usr/sbin/nologin -u 111 opendkim' 
returned error code 1. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package opendkim (--configure): installed opendkim package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 opendkim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have seen [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991685/usermod-cannot-lock-etc-passwd) that suggests using SUDO, but this is an automated process that I have no control over

Comment: Are there any stale `.lock` files in `/etc` (ex. `ls -l /etc/*.lock`)?

Comment: .pwd.lock, passwd.lock, group.lock, gshadow.lock, shadow.lock